# package video with .net application

Tags: .net, video

I am going to create an application using c# which can play local video. How can i:

1. Package the video with the application, without the end user able to copy or extract the video from the application?
2. Someone suggested encrypting the videos and decrypting it when it's going to be viewed. IMO this will take massive amount of CPU resource, no?

Comment: The various recording industries have had *so* much success DRM'ing their content that I can see why you'd want to go down this road...

Comment: i just want a simple method of protecting the videos from everyday home users... something that will at least hide the videos and not being displayed explicitly in some folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kirk Woll says in the comments, DRM has been a giant flop for the most part.  You are probably being too paranoid about this video.  That said, if you really, really feel the need to do this, then there are a couple of options:

- **simple obfuscation**: rename the file to something like data.bin.  Casual home users won't work that out.  Power users and coders could, if they wanted to.
- **simple encryption**: even  [rot13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) might be enough to relax your paranoia, maybe.  If not, a full blown encryption would not be so taxing on the CPU to worry about it.  Your browser does encryption every time you visit an HTTPS website.  Modern CPUs can deal with it without breaking a digital sweat.